# Solution of $3^x+x^2=1$ using calculus

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to find out the solutions of $3^x+x^2=1$ using calculus. If we double differentiate both sides and then take the logarithm, we get the value of $x$. 
After double differentiating, the equation becomes :
$$3^x \ln^2 3 + 2=0$$ and we can take the logarithm of $3^x$ and do that way. But is that a correct way? I doubt that. If not, why?

Also, how to calculate the values?

Comment: If $f$ is a differentiable function, then $f(a)=0$ does not imply $f'(a)=0$.

Comment: How will derivatives help you find the zeroes  on their own?

Comment: This is a numerical problem, really.  Calculus can help in that you can use it show that there is a unique minimum.  That, and a little work, will show that there must be exactly one other solution besides the obvious one.

Comment: @lulu Can you show that?

Comment: Sure.  The second derivative of the left hand has no zeroes so the first derivative can have at most one zero.  But it is obvious that it has at least one zero.

Comment: @lulu Yes, but that doesn't do the work. I mean, you can't find the solution. Any numerical way to find out the solution?

Comment: But it is trivial to solve numerically.  Let $f(x)=3^x+x^2$.  We note that $f(-.8)\approx 1.055243647$ and $f(-.7)\approx 0.953463057$.  So the solution is between $-.8$ and $-.7$.  Now cut that interval in half, and so on.

Comment: @lulu okay that way. Yes, I know that. It's more of an approximation.

Comment: That's what numerical methods are.

Comment: $t(x)=3^x+x^2$ is strictly increasing on $(0,+\infty)$ and $t(0)=1$

so that's the only zero on that interval.

on $(-\infty,-1)$ we have  $x^2+3^x > 1$ because $x^2 \geq 1$ and $3^x > 0$

so there's no solution there.

however, on the interval $(-1,0)$ you can only prove that there is a zero, at best you can approximate it numerically as it was mentioned in the above comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $x=0$ is a solution to the equation $3^x+x^2=1$.

Consider the function $f(x)=3^x+x^2-1$. Note that this function is positive for $x>0$, and it is positive for $x\leq -1$. Thus, the roots of this equation must belong to the set $(-1,0]$. The second derivative of this function is $f''(x)=3^x\ln(3)^2+2>0$, so we know that the first derivative $f'(x)=3^x\ln(3)+2x$ is strictly increasing and can therefore only have one root. Since $f'(-1)<0$ and $f'(0)>0$, by the intermediate value theorem there is a $c\in(-1,0]$ such that $f'(c)=0$. Thus, on each interval $(-\infty,c)$ and $[c,\infty)$ the function $f(x)$ can have at most one root.

We have already found the root on the interval $[c,\infty)$, so what remains is to find the root on $[-1,c)$. Since we know that $f(x)$ is strictly decreasing on that interval, and $f(-1)>0$, you could implement Newton's method with a starting guess of $x_0=-1$ in order to approximate the root.

Can we instead find a closed form expression for this root? No. This function does not permit us to solve for $x$ analytically; the best we will ever do is write down the solution in terms of special functions, which will also necessitate the use of approximations at the end of the day.

Comment: I'm just interested (though I've already accepted your answer) to know what special functions would you use for this.

Comment: @Mathbg I said the best we could do was use a special function; unfortunately I don't think I know such a function off of the top of my head. However, equations of the form $e^x+x=c$ can be solved using product-log functions, so it is not unreasonable to expect that there is *something* that would solve $e^x+x^2=c$, and from there it is a very short hop to $3^x+x^2=c$.